# Can't click with touchpad while typing

Tags: windows-10, touchpad, thinkpad

I'm using a ThinkPad to play Among Us. Whenever I try to click while moving, I have to stop moving, wait 1 second, and then click. I'm on Windows 10.I CAN move the mouse while typing though.